# Copy column but drop observations one row in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataset like this

```
df <- data.frame(letters = LETTERS[1:5],
                 numbers = 6:10)
df
  letters numbers
1       A       6
2       B       7
3       C       8
4       D       9
5       E      10
```

I would like to copy a column, but droping observations one row. I could do this manually:

```
df$numbers2 <- c(0, df$numbers[-length(df$numbers))
```

To get this result:

```
df
  letters numbers numbers2
1       A       6        0
2       B       7        6
3       C       8        7
4       D       9        8
5       E      10        9
```

Is there a function to perform this task?

Comment: `df$numbers2 <- dplyr::lag(df$numbers)`

Comment: `lag()` is exactly the function I was loonking for! Actually i used it before, but I was not remembering its name. Thank you very much!

Comment: Or without packages, use `head` - `c(0,head(df$numbers,-1))`

Comment: Well if we agree on `library(dplyr)` then `df <- df %>% mutate(numbers2 = lag(numbers))`

Comment: The dplyr solution is ok for me. Without packages I did using `c(0, df$numbers[-length(df$numbers))`, because data could have n observations.

Comment: @BrunoPinheiro - `head` deals with that, it just removes the last value.

Comment: @thelatemail Of corse!! `head(x, -1)`! I was not considering the "-1" argument. Very simple too!